# Listview min height

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a list view in which it has min height of 100dp (or 5 rows). Is this possible?The thing is I want to display this height as long as there are no or small number of items however the list can expand with more items being added.

I played so much with the layout with no luck

Thanks

Comment: You can have `minHeight` attribute for list item . And i did not get the second part of your question . Do explain properly .

Comment: minHeight in listview does not work when wrap_content is used. this is why I am asking if there is a way

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, care to specify why!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a minimum height that the list should use this in your ListView in the XML:

```
android:minHeight="100dp"
```

And to make the list expand every time there are new items (videos) set the ListView height to wrap_content:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: minHeight in listview does not work when wrap_content is used. this is why I am asking if there is a way . I tried above and it would just wrap_around

Comment: Ok, include the ListView in a LinearLayout with minHeight="100dp", layout_height="wrap_content" and vertical orienation, and for the ListView keep the both match_parent

Comment: hmm interesting.  that could work. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)